# scrapy is there a way to print json file without using -o -t parameters

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, scrapy

I am usually calling my spider like this:

```
scrapy crawl Spider -o fileName -t json
```

and I got the correct data printed in the `fileName` file as json formated.

Now I want to call my spider like this:

```
scrapy crawl Spider
```

#### my question

is there a way to print the output to a file without using the -o -t parameters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it can be done. add this to your settings

```
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
 'jsonlines': 'scrapy.contrib.exporter.JsonLinesItemExporter',
}
FEED_FORMAT = 'jsonlines'
FEED_URI = "NAME_OF_FILE.json"
```

For reference

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html

Comment: is there a way that the `Feed_Format` and the `Feed_Uri` be dynamic in the code?

Comment: you can try this
    `from scrapy.conf import settings`
    `settings.overrides[SETTING_TO_OVERRIDE] = VALUE`

Comment: The `jsonlines` exporter is for huge number of items. For normal use, it is not recommended.

Comment: You can set Feed_Format etc.. in the spider in 'custom_settings'. I would assume that you can the modify it at will - like you would any other class member data.

Comment: this should be `'jsonlines': 'scrapy.exporters.JsonLinesItemExporter'` for exporters now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i did it in *scrapy 2.6.1*

```
def open_spider(self, spider: YellowpagesCategorySpiderSpider):
    feeds = spider.settings.attributes['FEEDS'].value
    output_file_names = list(feeds)
    if len(output_file_names) > 1:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Only one output file is allowed, but {len(output_file_names)} were found")
    self.output_file_name = output_file_names[0]
```